# Menu creation problem

Tags: 7, views, nodes, routes

I am trying to create a new menu link. But the system doesn't allow me to do so.

**The path 'New' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.
The path 'testss' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.**

Answer (score 1):

A Drupal menu item can point to external URLs, URLs to files in the filesystem or an internal *path*. The latter has to exist before creating the menu item and access permissions are needed for the user creating it.

A path can point to a node or any other entity, or any path provided by a module (e.g a view from the Views module). Virtually any path can have any number of *aliases* but it's worth using the path in the menu items as aliases may change throughout the lifetime of the site, paths are less likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using the node and its id like "node/id#", it will pick up the alias if it has one.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create some content which has the path "new". Create a node and in the "URL Path Settings", give it an alias "new". Now, you should be able to create menu item with that link.

Comment: Yes i have create a block called new and after that i have try to add the Menu Link.. But its still giving me the same eroror

Comment: This is not how Drupal works. You need to see some video tutorials.

As said in my answer, you need to create "content". A block is not a content. A "node" is a content. Create a node and give it an alias "new". Then you should be set. 

Please accept my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a content eg article via node/add/article and use the url for the content aka node which is like node/[node:id] ; node:id is the numeric id number of the created content.

Drupal needs a valid path to create menu items. The link or path that you provide should exist or should be accessible.

You can go through these articles for a clear idea:
https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu
https://www.drupal.org/node/788972

Good luck